# Does spring boot internal logging support colored output to file

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, configuration, log4j

Does spring boot internal logging support redirection to file with colored keywords to make the tracing more pleasant experience? It hurts eyes to read the terminal log

Answer (score 2):

You can set `spring.output.ansi.enabled=always` on your application.properties

Spring boot will automatically use default colors to each level log, but you can change them, as you can see on:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-color-coded-output